# Building content for an existing liferay portal/server

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat6, windows-server, system-administration

I have a client with a LifeRay server set up to host their main website. I was tasked with adding a few dynamic pages to introduce more robust functionality.

I have downloaded their liferay and tomcat directories (in order to explore the current functionality- and learn about using liferay portals), but I'm not sure what to do with them, or where to start.
I have the IDE and I have a good amount of experience with similar technology.

They are using Tomcat 6.0.18 and LifeRay 5.2.3

My main question is: Where is all the web content located at?  And how do I get started in engineering additional web-based content?

Edit:
How would I go about adding new content- would I need access to the management interface?

Answer (score 2):

> Where is all the web content located at? And how do I get started in engineering additional web-based content?

Web-contents are located in database. Liferay already has a web-content portlet (Journal Article) through which you can add more web-content. You can check the [Liferay 5.2 User-guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/5.2/getting-started).

If you need some details as to what all developments can be done in liferay then you can refer to [Liferay's 5.2 Development guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/5.2/development).

> How would I go about adding new content - would I need access to the management interface?

[User-guide/Administration guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/5.2/administration) would help you with this. You can add content through the Control-panel or through the portlet configuration added on the page.

**Also would be great to advice the client to upgrade to Liferay version-6.** Since 5.2 is long outdated, the documentation is sparse and not so developer friendly.

If you required something else please update your question with additional details.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful, and has already given me alot of insight into this project.  The only specific question I have now is, how can I determine the workflow within the application.  And how does the application handle clickthrough and navigation?

Comment: You can include this question in your original question but I am afraid it is too broad a question and for this you would need to know about Portlet technology the different phases a portlet goes through like render, action, event etc. If you are only interested in Administration stuff I have updated the link to the User-guide but if you are interested in development and the underlying code flow check liferay source-code and read some good book about Liferay like Liferay-in-action.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Gave me a bit of perspective I didnt have before. As far as my project is concerned- they run version 5.2 so I downloaded the liferay 5.2 package and copied the portlets from the client into my dev machine.  One or two of them worked right away!

Comment: A few more details in case anyone is in the same boat.  I used the tomcat startup.sh on the command line after I dropped the portlets into a fresh install of v6.0. (I also pointed the database at my localhost- by changing the portal.properties jdbc params).    I am having trouble however, getting the IDE to be able to launch a server with the client portal that was built with Tomcat version 6.0.18   (Supported from 6.02 and newer).  Does anyone have any experience updating an existing Liferay system?